# Difference-in-differences regression in R: validity, assumptions, and correct usage

Tags: r, regression, assumptions, difference-in-difference, plm

I am currently writing one of my first empirical papers. As a side note, the topic is the effect of a CEO change on financial performance. Conceptually, I decided on the DiD approach, as I have a matrix of four groups: pre and post deal, as well as CEO change and no change. Using dummy variables, this is rather easy to implement in R. Now, I am just wondering if this makes sense, which assumptions I should check / write about checking, and if my implementation in R makes sense.

About the data: I aggregated financial data pre and post deal to single values such as averages because I need one value only per group for this to work. Then I ran many regression models for different dependent variables and with a varying number of control variables for rigidity. The effect I am looking for is described by my constructed interaction variable of the two dummies. Also, I use the `plm` function with "within" model estimation. Does all this make sense so far, especially the last part about the implementation? I think including an intercept with `lm` instead of `plm` doesn't really make sense here, also it would absorb most of the effect as I only have two time periods and two groups.

My R code for an example model looks something like this:

```
did <- plm(depdendant~ interaction + ceochange + time + control1 + control2 + log(control3) , data = ds, model = "within", index = c("id", "time"))
```

Honestly, I read through a lot of blog posts and questions on here but got a little overwhelmed and confused about what makes sense and what doesn't, so a short: "looks fine to me" would be enough for me as an answer. Also, the time variable is automatically excluded in the `stargazer` output as I noticed, plus the interaction variable when only indirectly including it via `*` and the two dummies is unfortunately only named as the time variable, I think because `stargazer` somehow cuts off everything before the last `$`.

Also, I am unsure about how to include the output as I have quite a lot of regression tables. Does it make sense to only show significant ones and push the rest to the appendix for referral?

Comment: Welcome. How many firms do you observe? Is `interaction` the manual instantiation of `ceochange * time`? And lastly, consider including `effect = "twoways"` inside of the function call. It isn't entirely necessary since you include `time` in the model, but it often saves you from extraneous output should you observe firms over a long time horizon.

Comment: Hi there. I observe around 250 firms only. Correct, interaction is ceochange:time just computed manually. I know „*“ would work more compactly, I just did it this way for formatting / name reasons. I tried that out, what does „twoway“ change? The calculation of p-values, correct? Also, my time horizon is technically more than two years, but i compute summary values for my dependent variables so that i only get one value for all pre and post periods, respectively.